# User migration fails

Tags: php, symfony, security, doctrine

1) I created User Class with **make:user** command:

[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg3Ne.png)

2) I generated migration file with **make:migration** command.

3) Here is the up() function in migration file:

```
    final class Version20181110133851 extends AbstractMigration
    {
         public function up(Schema $schema) : void
      {

       $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 
    'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

    $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE user ADD email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, ADD roles JSON NOT NULL, CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)');
    $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 ON user (email)');
       }
    ...
    }
```

4) This is what happens when I try to migrate to data base with  **doctrine:migration:migrate** command

[Image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz8eU.png)

and here is the content of the error:

```
  -> ALTER TABLE user ADD email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, ADD roles JSON NOT 
  NULL, CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)
  Migration 20181110133851 failed during Execution. Error An exception 
  occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE user ADD email VARCHAR(180) NOT 
  NULL, ADD roles JSON NOT NULL, CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)':

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
  in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
  server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, CHANGE id 
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)' at line 1

  In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 99:

  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE user ADD email 
  VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, ADD roles JSON NOT NULL, CHANGE id id INT 
  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRI
  MARY KEY (id)':

 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
 in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
 server version for
 the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, CHANGE id id INT 
 AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)' at line 1


 In PDOConnection.php line 109:

 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
 in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
 server version for
  the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, CHANGE id id INT 
 AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)' at line 1


  In PDOConnection.php line 107:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
 in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
  server version for
  the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, CHANGE id id INT 
  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)' at line 1
```

5) I've been trying to solve it for hours, but I am still a newbie and I don't think I am going to solve it myself.

6) My question: Where is the SYNTAX ERROR?

Comment: What is your mysql version? JSON fields are only available for 5.7+

Comment: C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.36-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Padam87 said, MariaDB does not support the native JSON type. If you can't upgrade your database for whatever reason but don't want to change the column type, just define the database version in the Doctrine properties and let Doctrine handle the conversion for you.

doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: '10.1.36-MariaDB'
```

This will add a comment in the table definition which Doctrine will use later to encode/decode the values.

Answer (score 1):

Mariadb 10.1 does not support the native json type, so you will have to use another type. Change your column definition, delete this migration, and generate a new one.

Alternatively, you can upgrade. Mariadb starts supporting the json type from 10.2.7 and up. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/

Comment: yep, it helped. Thanks. Ave Juve.